# How to change password using Google.GData.Apps of .net

Tags: c#, passwords

I am working on a password reset application, which works on Google domains. I used .net provisioning API. I goggled and tried everything but didn't find any way to change password.

Following link is used https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#updating_a_user_account

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried. [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: If it's not in the API you possibly can't. Can you link to the API documentation in your question?

Comment: @Rup I edited my question and added link that I used so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a very easy way

```
 AppsService service = new AppsService("domain", "adminusername", "adminpassword");
  UserEntry user = service.RetrieveUser("viresh1");
  user.Login.Password = "newpassword";
  service.UpdateUser(user);
```